# Unable to get property 'bind' of undefined or null reference

Tags: reactjs

```
render() {
        const { id, title } = this.props.toDo;

        return (
            <div style={this.getStyle()}>
                 <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.markedComplete.bind(this, id)} />
                <span>{title}</span>
                <button style={btnStyle} onClick={this.delTodo.bind(this, id)}>
                    X
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your error means the property `markedComplete` doesn't exist on `this` when you try and do: `this.markedComplete.bind`

Comment: You could add `this.markedComplete = this.markedComplete.bind(this)` in your constructor. That way, you should be able to use `onChange={() => this.markedComplete(id)}`.